# Trying to recreate the array.length method

Tags: javascript, methods, string-length

Like the title says, I am trying to recreate the array.length method and store it as a method on an object. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to set the length property to zero... I get this error that says

"should have a 'length' property that is initially 0"

and...

"Error: expected [Function] to equal 0".

I have included the test case below as to how the function is evaluated.

```
describe('Arrays/Errays', () => {
  let array, contents;

  beforeEach(() => {
    array = new Erray();
    contents = array.contents;
  });

  it('should have a \'length\' property that is initially 0', () => {
      expect(array.length).to.not.be(undefined);
      expect(array.length).to.be(0);
    })
  });
```

This is what I have coded so far.

```
function Erray() {
    this.contents = [];
    length: 0;
  }

Erray.prototype.length = function() {
      let length = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.contents.length; i++) {
        length++;
      }
      return length;
    }
  
var array = new Erray;
```

The second error leads me to believe a function is being returned to the test case and that is why it says "Error: expected [Function] to equal 0" with the word 'Function' in the brackets.

Any clues or tips as to why I am not passing my test case? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to create a getter for the length property.

```js
function Erray() {
  this.contents = [];
}
Object.defineProperty(Erray.prototype, 'length', {
  get() {
    return this.contents.length;
  }
});
var array = new Erray;
console.log(array.length);
array.contents.push(1);
console.log(array.length);
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Now I just have to understand why using Object.defineProperty and a getter... But thank you! I am sure I will figure it out!

Comment: @DaShaman Happy to help.